# Filter table visual based on maximum closest date to slicer in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I have a table and a slicer (showing today’s date by default).  I want when a user select a date from slicer, the table shows the closest date (date column in the table visual) to the selected in slicer.
[enter image description here][1]

I tried to create a measure that shows max date less than selected date in slicer:

Also a filter that shows which records should show and which is not:

And used that filter in filter section.

The “max dates” shows me the correct number but when I want to compare it with date column in the table visual, the filter measure doesn’t show correct data.
I tried to convert both “max dates” and date column to the same format both still didn’t work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UdW1.png

Earlier it just shows 0 for filter but now it doesn't show anything: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MXcq.png

Here is the PBIX file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGpF9qhF5GsPUFgrO2rMHkSpMUU94XbF/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Do not paste code as images, paste them as text with markdown code formatting.

Comment: I paste it as image but hasn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Filter` to:

```
Filter = 
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER('BankCard AccountSummary', [Date] = [max dates])
  )
```

Comment: Earlier it just shows 0 for filter but now it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Can you share a PBIX? Add a link to it on a public share.

Comment: Thanks, here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGpF9qhF5GsPUFgrO2rMHkSpMUU94XbF/view?usp=drive_link